# Oracle Self-Join

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, self-join

Im working through some self-join examples and I am drawing a blank on the following example. Its the last example at the following link [Self-Join Example](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-self-join/)

```
SELECT
   e1.hire_date,
  (e1.first_name || ' ' || e1.last_name) employee1,
  (e2.first_name || ' ' || e2.last_name) employee2  
FROM
    employees e1
INNER JOIN employees e2 ON
    e1.employee_id > e2.employee_id
    AND e1.hire_date = e2.hire_date
ORDER BY  
   e1.hire_date DESC,
   employee1, 
   employee2;
```

I dont understand why I need to check if Employee_id from the first instance of employee is greater than employee_id from the second instance of employee.

If anyone can provide a good explanation for this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Required create/insert scripts.

```
CREATE TABLE employees
  (
    employee_id NUMBER 
                GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY START WITH 108 
                PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    phone      VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
    hire_date  DATE NOT NULL          ,
    manager_id NUMBER( 12, 0 )        , -- fk
    job_title  VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_employees_manager 
        FOREIGN KEY( manager_id )
        REFERENCES employees( employee_id )
        ON DELETE CASCADE
  );

Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (107,'Summer','Payne','summer.payne@example.com','515.123.8181',to_date('07-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),106,'Public Accountant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (106,'Rose','Stephens','rose.stephens@example.com','515.123.8080',to_date('07-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),2,'Accounting Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (101,'Annabelle','Dunn','annabelle.dunn@example.com','515.123.4444',to_date('17-SEP-16','DD-MON-RR'),2,'Administration Assistant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (1,'Tommy','Bailey','tommy.bailey@example.com','515.123.4567',to_date('17-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),null,'President');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (3,'Blake','Cooper','blake.cooper@example.com','515.123.4569',to_date('13-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Administration Vice President');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (2,'Jude','Rivera','jude.rivera@example.com','515.123.4568',to_date('21-SEP-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Administration Vice President');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (11,'Tyler','Ramirez','tyler.ramirez@example.com','515.124.4269',to_date('28-SEP-16','DD-MON-RR'),9,'Accountant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (10,'Ryan','Gray','ryan.gray@example.com','515.124.4169',to_date('16-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),9,'Accountant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (14,'Elliot','Brooks','ellibrooks@example.com','515.124.4567',to_date('07-DEC-16','DD-MON-RR'),9,'Accountant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (12,'Elliott','James','elliott.james@example.com','515.124.4369',to_date('30-SEP-16','DD-MON-RR'),9,'Accountant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (13,'Albert','Watson','albert.watson@example.com','515.124.4469',to_date('07-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),9,'Accountant');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (9,'Mohammad','Peterson','mohammad.peterson@example.com','515.124.4569',to_date('17-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),2,'Finance Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (104,'Harper','Spencer','harper.spencer@example.com','515.123.7777',to_date('07-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),2,'Human Resources Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (4,'Louie','Richardson','louie.richardson@example.com','590.423.4567',to_date('03-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),3,'Programmer');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (5,'Nathan','Cox','nathan.cox@example.com','590.423.4568',to_date('21-MAY-16','DD-MON-RR'),4,'Programmer');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (8,'Bobby','Torres','bobby.torres@example.com','590.423.5567',to_date('07-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),4,'Programmer');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (7,'Charles','Ward','charles.ward@example.com','590.423.4560',to_date('05-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),4,'Programmer');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (6,'Gabriel','Howard','gabriel.howard@example.com','590.423.4569',to_date('25-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),4,'Programmer');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (102,'Emma','Perkins','emma.perkins@example.com','515.123.5555',to_date('17-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Marketing Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (103,'Amelie','Hudson','amelie.hudson@example.com','603.123.6666',to_date('17-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),102,'Marketing Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (105,'Gracie','Gardner','gracie.gardner@example.com','515.123.8888',to_date('07-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),2,'Public Relations Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (17,'Frederick','Price','frederick.price@example.com','515.127.4563',to_date('24-DEC-16','DD-MON-RR'),15,'Purchasing Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (16,'Alex','Sanders','alex.sanders@example.com','515.127.4562',to_date('18-MAY-16','DD-MON-RR'),15,'Purchasing Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (18,'Ollie','Bennett','ollie.bennett@example.com','515.127.4564',to_date('24-JUL-16','DD-MON-RR'),15,'Purchasing Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (19,'Louis','Wood','louis.wood@example.com','515.127.4565',to_date('15-NOV-16','DD-MON-RR'),15,'Purchasing Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (20,'Dexter','Barnes','dexter.barnes@example.com','515.127.4566',to_date('10-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),15,'Purchasing Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (15,'Rory','Kelly','rory.kelly@example.com','515.127.4561',to_date('07-DEC-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Purchasing Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (49,'Isabella','Cole','isabella.cole@example.com','011.44.1344.619268',to_date('15-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Sales Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (48,'Jessica','Woods','jessica.woods@example.com','011.44.1344.429278',to_date('10-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Sales Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (47,'Ella','Wallace','ella.wallace@example.com','011.44.1344.467268',to_date('05-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Sales Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (46,'Ava','Sullivan','ava.sullivan@example.com','011.44.1344.429268',to_date('01-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Sales Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (50,'Mia','West','mia.west@example.com','011.44.1344.429018',to_date('29-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Sales Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (56,'Evie','Harrison','evie.harrison@example.com','011.44.1344.486508',to_date('23-NOV-16','DD-MON-RR'),46,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (57,'Scarlett','Gibson','scarlett.gibson@example.com','011.44.1345.429268',to_date('30-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),47,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (58,'Ruby','Mcdonald','ruby.mcdonald@example.com','011.44.1345.929268',to_date('04-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),47,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (59,'Chloe','Cruz','chloe.cruz@example.com','011.44.1345.829268',to_date('01-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),47,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (60,'Isabelle','Marshall','isabelle.marshall@example.com','011.44.1345.729268',to_date('10-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),47,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (61,'Daisy','Ortiz','daisy.ortiz@example.com','011.44.1345.629268',to_date('15-DEC-16','DD-MON-RR'),47,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (62,'Freya','Gomez','freya.gomez@example.com','011.44.1345.529268',to_date('03-NOV-16','DD-MON-RR'),47,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (80,'Elizabeth','Dixon','elizabeth.dixon@example.com','011.44.1644.429262',to_date('04-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),50,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (64,'Florence','Freeman','florence.freeman@example.com','011.44.1346.229268',to_date('19-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),48,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (65,'Alice','Wells','alice.wells@example.com','011.44.1346.329268',to_date('24-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),48,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (66,'Charlotte','Webb','charlotte.webb@example.com','011.44.1346.529268',to_date('23-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),48,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (67,'Sienna','Simpson','sienna.simpson@example.com','011.44.1346.629268',to_date('24-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),48,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (68,'Matilda','Stevens','matilda.stevens@example.com','011.44.1346.729268',to_date('21-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'),48,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (69,'Evelyn','Tucker','evelyn.tucker@example.com','011.44.1343.929268',to_date('11-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),49,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (70,'Eva','Porter','eva.porter@example.com','011.44.1343.829268',to_date('23-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),49,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (71,'Millie','Hunter','millie.hunter@example.com','011.44.1343.729268',to_date('24-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),49,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (72,'Sofia','Hicks','sofia.hicks@example.com','011.44.1343.629268',to_date('23-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),49,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (73,'Lucy','Crawford','lucy.crawford@example.com','011.44.1343.529268',to_date('24-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),49,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (74,'Elsie','Henry','elsie.henry@example.com','011.44.1343.329268',to_date('21-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'),49,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (75,'Imogen','Boyd','imogen.boyd@example.com','011.44.1644.429267',to_date('11-MAY-16','DD-MON-RR'),50,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (76,'Layla','Mason','layla.mason@example.com','011.44.1644.429266',to_date('19-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),50,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (77,'Rosie','Morales','rosie.morales@example.com','011.44.1644.429265',to_date('24-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),50,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (78,'Maya','Kennedy','maya.kennedy@example.com','011.44.1644.429264',to_date('23-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'),50,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (79,'Esme','Warren','esme.warren@example.com','011.44.1644.429263',to_date('24-MAY-16','DD-MON-RR'),50,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (55,'Grace','Ellis','grace.ellis@example.com','011.44.1344.987668',to_date('09-DEC-16','DD-MON-RR'),46,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (54,'Lily','Fisher','lily.fisher@example.com','011.44.1344.498718',to_date('30-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),46,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (53,'Sophia','Reynolds','sophia.reynolds@example.com','011.44.1344.478968',to_date('20-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),46,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (52,'Sophie','Owens','sophie.owens@example.com','011.44.1344.345268',to_date('24-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),46,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (51,'Poppy','Jordan','poppy.jordan@example.com','011.44.1344.129268',to_date('30-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),46,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (63,'Phoebe','Murray','phoebe.murray@example.com','011.44.1346.129268',to_date('11-NOV-16','DD-MON-RR'),48,'Sales Representative');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (85,'Holly','Shaw','holly.shaw@example.com','650.509.1876',to_date('27-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (86,'Emilia','Holmes','emilia.holmes@example.com','650.509.2876',to_date('20-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (87,'Molly','Rice','molly.rice@example.com','650.509.3876',to_date('24-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (88,'Ellie','Robertson','ellie.robertson@example.com','650.509.4876',to_date('07-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (89,'Jasmine','Hunt','jasmine.hunt@example.com','650.505.1876',to_date('14-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (90,'Eliza','Black','eliza.black@example.com','650.505.2876',to_date('13-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (91,'Lilly','Daniels','lilly.daniels@example.com','650.505.3876',to_date('11-JUL-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (92,'Abigail','Palmer','abigail.palmer@example.com','650.505.4876',to_date('19-DEC-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (93,'Georgia','Mills','georgia.mills@example.com','650.501.1876',to_date('04-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (94,'Maisie','Nichols','maisie.nichols@example.com','650.501.2876',to_date('03-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (95,'Eleanor','Grant','eleanor.grant@example.com','650.501.3876',to_date('01-JUL-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (96,'Hannah','Knight','hannah.knight@example.com','650.501.4876',to_date('17-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (97,'Harriet','Ferguson','harriet.ferguson@example.com','650.507.9811',to_date('24-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (98,'Amber','Rose','amber.rose@example.com','650.507.9822',to_date('23-MAY-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (99,'Bella','Stone','bella.stone@example.com','650.507.9833',to_date('21-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (100,'Thea','Hawkins','thea.hawkins@example.com','650.507.9844',to_date('13-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (81,'Lola','Ramos','lola.ramos@example.com','650.507.9876',to_date('24-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (82,'Willow','Reyes','willow.reyes@example.com','650.507.9877',to_date('23-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (83,'Ivy','Burns','ivy.burns@example.com','650.507.9878',to_date('21-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (84,'Erin','Gordon','erin.gordon@example.com','650.507.9879',to_date('03-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Shipping Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (33,'Reggie','Simmons','reggie.simmons@example.com','650.124.8234',to_date('10-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (44,'Emily','Hamilton','emily.hamilton@example.com','650.121.2874',to_date('15-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (43,'Olivia','Ford','olivia.ford@example.com','650.121.2994',to_date('29-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (42,'Amelia','Myers','amelia.myers@example.com','650.121.8009',to_date('17-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (41,'Connor','Hayes','connor.hayes@example.com','650.121.1834',to_date('06-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (26,'Leon','Powell','leon.powell@example.com','650.124.1214',to_date('16-JUL-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (27,'Kai','Long','kai.long@example.com','650.124.1224',to_date('28-SEP-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (28,'Aaron','Patterson','aaron.patterson@example.com','650.124.1334',to_date('14-JAN-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (29,'Roman','Hughes','roman.hughes@example.com','650.124.1434',to_date('08-MAR-16','DD-MON-RR'),21,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (30,'Austin','Flores','austin.flores@example.com','650.124.5234',to_date('20-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (31,'Ellis','Washington','ellis.washington@example.com','650.124.6234',to_date('30-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (32,'Jamie','Butler','jamie.butler@example.com','650.124.7234',to_date('16-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),22,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (45,'Isla','Graham','isla.graham@example.com','650.121.2004',to_date('09-JUL-16','DD-MON-RR'),25,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (34,'Seth','Foster','seth.foster@example.com','650.127.1934',to_date('14-JUN-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (35,'Carter','Gonzales','carter.gonzales@example.com','650.127.1834',to_date('26-AUG-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (36,'Felix','Bryant','felix.bryant@example.com','650.127.1734',to_date('12-DEC-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (37,'Ibrahim','Alexander','ibrahim.alexander@example.com','650.127.1634',to_date('06-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),23,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (38,'Sonny','Russell','sonny.russell@example.com','650.121.1234',to_date('14-JUL-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (39,'Kian','Griffin','kian.griffin@example.com','650.121.2034',to_date('26-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (40,'Caleb','Diaz','caleb.diaz@example.com','650.121.2019',to_date('12-FEB-16','DD-MON-RR'),24,'Stock Clerk');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (25,'Ronnie','Perry','ronnie.perry@example.com','650.123.5234',to_date('16-NOV-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Stock Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (24,'Callum','Jenkins','callum.jenkins@example.com','650.123.4234',to_date('10-OCT-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Stock Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (23,'Jackson','Coleman','jackson.coleman@example.com','650.123.3234',to_date('01-MAY-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Stock Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (22,'Liam','Henderson','liam.henderson@example.com','650.123.2234',to_date('10-APR-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Stock Manager');
Insert into EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,PHONE,HIRE_DATE,MANAGER_ID,JOB_TITLE) values (21,'Jaxon','Ross','jaxon.ross@example.com','650.123.1234',to_date('18-JUL-16','DD-MON-RR'),1,'Stock Manager');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't have any condition on employee ID at all you'd end up with records where a self-match had occurred, e.g. the results would show "Gracie Gardner was hired on the same day as Gracie Gardner"

We could then put `ON e1.employee_id <> e2.employee_id` - this would prevent Gracie matching with Gracie, but you'd then find "Gracie Gardner was hired on the same day as Summer Payne" and "Summer Payne was hired on the same day as Gracie Gardner" - i.e. you'd get "duplicate records" in terms of "person paired with person", each name being mentioned both ways round

Using greater than prevents this, and effectively means that any given pair of names only appears once. Because Gracie's ID is less than Summer's, you'll get `Gracie in e1` paired with `Summer in e2` but you won't get `Summer in e1` paired with `Gracie in e2`

Another way of visualizing it is with a square/matrix

```
   no id      id1<>id2   id1<id2

     A B C      A B C      A B C
   A * * *    A   * *    A  
   B * * *    B *   *    B *  
   C * * *    C * *      C * *
```

In the first square you have everything matched with everything. In the second you remove AA / BB / CC matches but you still have AB and BA, AC and CA etc. In the third square you only have uniquely paired letters (AB but not BA, AC but not CA, ...)

Comment: Idle side curio; in the days before window functions, doing some query like this was a way of establishing some rolling count.. If you were to do `t1.id, count(*) FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.id < t2.id GROUP BY t1.id` then you'd get the lowest t1 ID repeated N times, the next lowest repeated N-1 times... when grouped and counted you'd have e.g. IDs of A, B, C with counters going 3, 2, 1.. In descriptive terms you could say e.g. "3 poople were hired after Alfred, 2 people were hired after Bertie, 1 person hired after Charlie".. And you'd change `<` to `>` to run the count the other way...

Comment: @CaiusJard - with some care (to handle duplicates and `null` when the ordering column is not a primary key); and the same could be used more generally to implement, for example, analytic `sum()`, not just `count()`. It could be made to work for `partition by` clause, and for different handling of ties (similar to "range between..." vs "rows between..."). Good thing we don't have to do it ourselves though!

Answer (score 0):

If you compare on `!=` (instead of `>`):

```sql
SELECT e1.hire_date,
       e1.first_name || ' ' || e1.last_name AS employee1,
       e2.first_name || ' ' || e2.last_name AS employee2  
FROM   employees e1
       INNER JOIN employees e2
       ON e1.employee_id != e2.employee_id AND e1.hire_date = e2.hire_date
ORDER BY
       e1.hire_date DESC,
       employee1, 
       employee2;
```

Then you will find you get duplicate rows with the values with the names swapped round:

> | HIRE_DATE | EMPLOYEE1 | EMPLOYEE2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 07-DEC-16 | Elliot Brooks | Rory Kelly |
> | 07-DEC-16 | Rory Kelly | Elliot Brooks |

If you use just `>` then you only get one of the two rows as the other is filtered out:

> | HIRE_DATE | EMPLOYEE1 | EMPLOYEE2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 07-DEC-16 | Rory Kelly | Elliot Brooks |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e585c73e2a11464db371d8ad88b1159)*